Linux Mint 22, python and vpn-slice error (ModuleNotFound)
Hi folks i've been using vpn-slice forever on past Mint versions without issue, but I've just upgraded to 22 of mint, and trying to get vpnslice to work again. Following directions here https://github.com/dlenski/vpn-slice
sudo pip3 install "vpn-slice[dnspython,setproctitle]"

produces
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed

So i tried using pipx
sudo pipx install "vpn-slice[dnspython,setproctitle]"

which seemed to work, however, when i do
sudo vpn-slice --self-test

i get
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/vpn-slice", line 5, in
from vpn_slice.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vpn_slice'

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Please provide the python code.
